# 4 devices and one of them defective, what is the fastest way to find which one is defective

Tags: contest-math, puzzle, machine-learning

I have problem to solve this puzzle

4 devices and one of them defective, what is the fastest way to find which one is defective

and this is a picture for demionstation 
[image]

you can generate as many as you want, all of them go to the orange area and then adding them and once you click calculate it needs one hour for the process

Now one of them is defective, it generates 1 instead of 2

What is the fastest way to know which on of them defective

you can do it in one calculate but how ?!

Comment: And what does calculate calculate?

Comment: Addition, adding all numbers from the generator

Comment: Perhaps you generate from the first box once, the second box twice, the third box thrice and the fourth box four times? Then the amount of shortfall indicates which box is defective.

Comment: The amount is calculated in the orange box before you hit calculate which takes 1 hour for each calculate

Comment: (And if you generate once from first, twice from second, four times from third, eight times from fourth, you could even detect any number of defective devices in any combination, in a single calculate.)

Comment: @ Daniel Schepler     that's correct you solved it in no time 0__0  good job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activating generator $1$ once, generator $2$ twice, generator $3$ three times and generator $4$ $4$ times gives the results $19,18,17,16$ , if generator $1,2,3,4$ is defect respectively.

Comment: Nice, but you may choose the wrong one in the second try, since there're 2 left. Anyway as I said before you can solve it using one try I think the secret in the orange area that add them

Comment: if you have 1 2 3 4 generators  and you have tried  the first 2  if the result is 4 then one of the other generators is defective, so  the remaining generators are  3 and 4 , you have to try one of them to check whether its the correct one or not, so  you may choose the defective generator since you have 2 possibilities remaining not only one.

Comment: @AhmadzIssa Is it that ? I misunderestood the question. I thought I can activate or not activate any generator and have to minize the steps to find out the defect one.